# How to execute a SELECT statement with a function called in the WHERE clause in a VB.NET application?

Tags: vb.net, t-sql

I have a table of data with a column "Date".
I found a SQL function which returns the European's week number of a date (The way to count the week number it is different from the US's way).

I wrote my request as a string in my VB.NET application : (I included the function)

```vb
Connexion.Open()

Dim Rq As String = "CREATE FUNCTION dbo.F_NUMERO_SEMAINE_ISO  (@JOUR datetime)
    RETURNS int
    AS
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @NSI int;

       SET @NSI = DATEPART(wk, @JOUR) + 1 - DATEPART(wk, CAST(DATEPART(yy, @JOUR) as CHAR(4)) + '0104');

    -- cas particuliers : du 1 au 3 janvier, le jour peut appartenir à la dernière semaine de l'année précédente
       IF @NSI = 0
          SET @NSI = dbo.F_NUMERO_SEMAINE_ISO(CAST(DATEPART(yy,@JOUR)-1 AS CHAR(4)) + '12' + CAST(24 + DATEPART(DAY, @JOUR) AS CHAR(2))) + 1;

    -- cas particuliers : du 29 au 31 décembre, le jour peut appartenir à la première semaine de l'année suivante
       IF (DATEPART(mm, @JOUR) = 12) AND ( (DATEPART(dd, @JOUR) - DATEPART(dw, @JOUR) ) >= 28 ) 
          SET @NSI = 1;

       RETURN @NSI;
    END

    GO

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.DATA WHERE dbo.F_NUMERO_SEMAINE_ISO(Date) = 34
    DROP function dbo.F_NUMERO_SEMAINE_ISO"

Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand(Rq, Connexion)
Try
    Dim Reader As Integer = Cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    MessageBox.Show("nb nouveau : " & Reader.ToString())
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    Cmd.Dispose()
    Connexion.Close()
End Try
```

I have an error on the line of the cmd.executeScalar()

> "Syntax error to 'GO'" AND "Syntax error to 'F_NUMERO_SEMAINE_ISO'"

I don't know how I can do to call my SQL function from my vb.net code, but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Why are you creating the `FUNCTION` in the VB SQL statement? The Function should already exist on the Instance. As for the error, `GO` isn't a T-SQL operator; it's used by SSMS, `sqlcmd` and some other IDEs as a batch Separator and is interpreted by the application, not the the RDBMS. Referencing a function from VB.net in a SQL statement is no different to how you normally would.

Comment: That's because I'm use to first try my queries on SSMS to test them, and usually I just need simple SELECT or COUNT so I make a copy-paste in my vb.net request. And I don't know where I can create it otherwise ...

Comment: Use SSMS to create your objects; or your preferred IDE. But don't create the objects as part of the SQL statement from your application.

Comment: But I don't understand, if I create my function on SSMS, how can I call it from my VB.net code ?

Comment: **how can I call it from my VB.net code"* The same way you would in SSMS; using SQL. You're connecting to the same database. `SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable;` will return the same data against the same database, regardless of the application you use. Databases aren't user and application specific when hosted on an instance.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much ! Thanks to you I knew what to search ! I find the way to create a SQL scalar-valued function here : http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-scalar-functions/ And I changed my code, it's working fine !  (I removed all and I just let my SELECT COUNT clause)